# Notification Center message via AppleScript/osascript -- specify an application name and icon

Tags: applescript, notifications

When sending a notification to OS X's Notification Center via AppleScript's `osascript`, such as in:

```
osascript -e 'display notification "Finished that long running task." with title "Finally!"'
```

The Notification Center shows "AppleScript Editor" as the notification's source:

[image: NotificationCenter]

Is there a possibility to specify a different source (as in application) and icon when sending a notification this way?

Comment: Pro tip: You can use emoji in AppleScript notifications.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with AppleScript but it is with [terminal-notifier](https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier):

```
-sender ID         The bundle identifier of the application that should be
shown as the sender, including its icon.
-appIcon URL       The URL of a image to display instead of the application
icon (Mavericks+ only)
```

For example:

```
terminal-notifier -title title -message message -sender com.apple.TextEdit
```

Comment: Thank you, `terminal-notifier` is perfect. Btw, it's available via homebrew.

Answer (score 3):

You can "tell an app" to display the notification, but you also need to do this as root for the icon to show.

For instance, from a terminal window, try:

```
sudo osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display notification "Finished that long running task." with title "Finally!"'
```

You can change `"System Events"` to any other application name.

Comment: No matter what I specify as application name, it always shows with the Script Editor icon and application name.

Comment: I think I just figured this one out. When I run my script as "me" it shows the apple script icon as well... but when I "sudo" the script, it shows the icon of the program I "told". I.e. you need to call the command as "root" to make it "order" other applications to do stuff... makes some sense... I updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer, since it uses the same tech as the question author. Works for me!